# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type in Tridion DD4T setup

Tags: 2013, dd4t

I have created a new local setup for a DD4T publication in MVC4/Tridion 2013 sp1. In the pagecontroller I am querying for the component and successfully passing it's tcmid using viewbag to my view. I am getting error in the view as shown below, though the argument has the correct component id which is already published in broker-

PS: Please ignore my hardcoding of id's as I'll configure it later

Controller -

```
var client = new CDS.ContentDeliveryService(new Uri("tridion2013server", UriKind.Absolute));

int publicationId = xx;
int componentTemplateId = xxxxx;

var componentPresentations = client.ComponentPresentations
                                    .Where(u => u.PublicationId == publicationId && u.TemplateId == componentTemplateId)
                                    .ToList();
try
{
    foreach (var cp in componentPresentations)
    {
        if (cp.ComponentId.Equals(xxxxx))
        {
            ViewBag.headerCompId = cp.ComponentId.ToString();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View -

```
@{ Layout = "";
    var lf = new LinkFactory();      
    var cf = new ComponentFactory();      
    lf.LinkProvider = new TridionLinkProvider();      
    var compId = "tcm:73-" + ViewBag.headerCompId;

    var comp = cf.GetComponent(compId);    **// error - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type**
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain the purpose of this code? It's a bit unclear what you're intending to achieve. It looks like you've got logic in your View which is not advised for MVC (and by extension DD4T).

Comment: I have now separated the code - the c# code is in the controller and not in the view.

Comment: Thanks that is a little clearer, what exactly are you trying to do though? It looks like you're trying to use a common component for the header on each page - is that correct?

Comment: right, for header i m trying to get the it's comp id through odata and passing the id to view using viewbag

Comment: If your Header is a DCP - you could request it from the broker via DD4T. It still looks like you have too much code in your view. I would not expect to see use of Component Factory in the View. That should happen in the Controller.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against using both the Content Delivery Service AND DD4T to retrieve content from the broker database. Seeing as how you already know the component to retrieve why query the Content Delivery Service for it? And if you do want to query it is more efficient to do so via the Broker libraries then via the Content Delivery Service...

As for your specific problem: I've looked through all of the code and cannot find any code in DD4T that would throw the exception as you have stated; can you provide us with a stacktrace? I could not find any code that would throw the exception as you have mentioned...